# Iphone Table Cell Sizes

Tags: iphone, sdk, uitableview

I'm using custom cells in my table view. I have the height of the cells set but for only the 10th cell in the table I need to resize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the `UITableViewDelegate` method `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

Something like this:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView: (UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if ( indexPath.row == 10 )
         return 100.0;

     return 40.0;
}
```

Comment: this worked, now I have a button when you click it will add 10 more cells to the table, how do I get the table to update with those ten cells

Comment: [tableView reloadData].  Or you can call [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths: ...   In each case you need to update your datasource first.